# Strange behavior of \footnotemark/\footnotetext in revtex4-1

Tags: footnotes, revtex

I've been writing using the class `revtex4-1` (for the APS journals...) and have come across the following: When using `footnotemark` and `footnotetext` they each advance the `footnote` counter rather than only `footnotetext`, as in the `article` class. Here's a minimal example (I use `nofootinbib` to override the default which is to place the footnotes with the bibliography..., and the minipage is so that I can show you the output, it has no other effect):

```
\documentclass[nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
hello\footnotemark

\footnotetext{hello's text}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2 \footnotemark\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
\footnotetext{equations footnote}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following strange output:

[image]

Sure, I can fix it by inserting a `\addtocounter{-1}{footnote}` between the two commands...but I'm more interested in why this is happening, and whether its a bug.

---

hmmm. I just checked, it works fine with `revtex4`, so this is probably a bug in `revtex4-1`...Still, I'd like to hear your input.

Comment: I'd say this is a bug: it's clearly not what you'd expect and is not in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APS Author Guide for REVTeX 4.1 (apsguide4-1.pdf) says

> Avoid custom footnotes using
>   \footnotemark and \footnotetext
>   [except in the context of tables (see
>   Section VIII.5)].

So, don't do that...

Comment: hmmm. Yup. this is the correct answer. I thought I needed to use it because I wanted a footnote inside an equation...but I guess that using footnote works also inside an equation...atleast in REVTeX 4.1 Thanks!